# How to do multiple time series forecasting i.e. forecasting for each customer

Tags: r, time-series

I have the following month-wise data for each customer.

I would like to do a 3-month forecast for each customer.

Note:many obs have zeros(no transaction)------Need to tackle this sparse dataset

```
         CustomerName        01/2009 02/2009 03/2009 04/2009 05/2009 06/2009 07/2009 08/2009 09/2009 10/2009
         Aaron Bergman         0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00     0.0 4270.87    0.00    0.00       0
         Aaron Hawkins         0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00     0.0    0.00  455.04    0.00       0
         Aaron Smayling        136.29  4658.69 0.00    119.34  4674.16  0.0    0.00    0.00    0.00       0
         Adam Bellavance       0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    2107.55  0.0    0.00    0.00    0.00       0
         Adam Hart             60.52   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00     0.0    0.00    0.00    0.00       0
         Adam Shillingsburg    0.00    1749.50 125.86  0.00    0.00     5689.4 3275.74 1296.30 9887.52    0
         Adrian Barton         0.00    66.00    0.00    0.00    0.00     55.0    0.00    0.00    0.00     0
         Adrian Hane           0.00    23.66    0.00    0.00    46.22     0.0    0.00    0.00    0.00     0
         Adrian Shami          10.00    0.00    0.00    33.00    0.00    48.0    0.00    0.00    42.00    0
         Aimee Bixby           56.33    22.99    0.00    44.28    0.00     0.0    0.00   66.12   0.00    48.22
```

How can i do some sort of batch times series forecasting say using auto.arima for each customer  ......

Comment: Please add the data as a minimal example code and show the expected output based on this example data. This will make it easier for us to find an answer...

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "batch"?  If you want to base your time series modeling on sales by quarter, it is trivial to convert your dataframe to a `zoo` object and group dates by quarters.

Comment: @ edouard  Maybe i used'batch' in the wrong context...what i simply require is forecasting for each customer maybe using a loop (multiple series forecasting)...Also i have just given a subset of data ..actually it has more than 3 years of values for each customer...I have made an attempt which i will be sharing asap......